# Div Background Image Fixed With Bottom Parallax

Tags: html, css

My website is divided into 2 parts, a main part where there is a fixed background and a bottom part where there is a parallax effect.

Here's the structure of my `HTML`

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

The parallax is working just fine but the whole bottom part(where the parallax should appear) is getting covered by the background image of the previous `div`.

Here's the `CSS`

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

#main::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.9), rgba(255,255,255,.9)), url("../images/reverse-background.webp") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    will-change: transform;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I tried `position: sticky` for the background image but then the background image disappears and the bottom `div` becomes the background of the whole page.

So, what I want to achieve is for the background image to appear as long as the main `div` is being scrolled and for the image to end at the **end** of the div so that the bottom parallax is not hidden.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdyh51o9/1/) to illustrate the problem.